# Storing records in batches of 12 sql

Tags: c#

Is it possible to store data in sets or batches of 12 in sql? I have a query which before inserting a new row should check if the existing records are equal or less than twelve. If they are twelve then it should create a new batch which also stores a maximum of twelve records.

Comment: You need to define what constitutes a batch.

Comment: The batch basically constitutes of all the details of the table which I named Bills. Like in my case i have billdate,amountpaid,balancedue,maximumamamountpaid.Now after a one year period i want to start adding new details(billdate,amountpaid,balancedue,maximumamamountpaid) automatically yet keeping the existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in concept of data batching in SQL Server, or any other SQL-like database out there. What you're describing is data grouping/relations, which is the responsibility of the database designer to figure out. What you should do is create a related table, called Batches. Give it a primary key. Then place that primary key column into your actual table with data as a foreign key. The logic about when batches are created should probably be defined in a trigger, or define the logic in a UDF and set the Default Value of that BatchId column to the result of that UDF.